# Unauthorized user access to some url

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I use Oauth and want to create user but have error

```
POST http://localhost:4200/proxy/user/createUser 401 (Unauthorized)
```

In spring i have some configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/createUser", "/user/**", "/user/createUser", "proxy/user/createUser").permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.formLogin().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/createUser", "/register", "/token", "/token/createUser", "proxy/user/createUser").permitAll();
        http.requestMatchers()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

What configuration changes are required to enable access to `../createUser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()` this is creating problem in code. just change in `WebSecurity` as

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/createUser", "/user/**", "/user/createUser", "proxy/user/createUser")
         .permitAll()
         .formLogin().disable();

}}`
```

AND

change in `ResourceServerConfig` as

`http.authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/createUser", "/register", "/token", "/token/createUser",
"proxy/user/createUser")
    .permitAll();`

for details checkout [Security-config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/helloworld-javaconfig.html).

Comment: Still unauthorized

Comment: Have you made changes in `ResourceServerConfig`?

Comment: Yes but i must in Websecurity http.formLogin().disable() because i have error can't resolve method

Comment: I have also AuthorizationServerConfig maybe this class make conflict

Comment: can you once try only with end-point with which you are trying i.e use only `"proxy/user/createUser"` in antMatchers? so that we can atleast know what is happening with this end-point. Thanks

Comment: crateUser is my api url to registration user i set breakpoint. Order call method is firstly from ResourceServerConfig and Websecurity is call later.  When i try with "proxy/user/createUser i have only error in front side that (401) Unathorized

Comment: createUser is call after login and the user is not logged in yet

Comment: are you not able to login? does your end-point `http://localhost:4200/proxy/user/createUser` is accessed by any role?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176067/discussion-between-yogendra-mishra-and-wojciech-abacki).

Comment: in the end I found a problem, it was enough in the interceptor on the front side exclude some path